# How to add a new CSS class to a Link Badge if the value is 0?

Tags: css, drupal-7

I'm using the small module [Link Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_badges) to display a badge with the amount of flagged nodes next to a link to the View in question. It works great and I've styled the badge to my needs. This is the current HTML code:

```
<a class="menu__link menu__link link-badge-wrapper">
  <span class="link-badge-text">My View</span>
  <span class="link-badge-badge-wrapper">
    <span class="link-badge link-badge-menu_badges_execute_view">0</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Now, I'd like to display the badge a little bit differently (other colors etc.) when the value is 0. I thought about doing this by adding a new CSS class `link-badge-zero` to the value.

```
<a class="menu__link menu__link link-badge-wrapper">
  <span class="link-badge-text">My View</span>
  <span class="link-badge-badge-wrapper">
    <span class="link-badge link-badge-zero link-badge-menu_badges_execute_view">0</span>
  </span>
</a>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: please upload your code to jsfiddle it's really hard to understand what you want to achieve this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to add a class if the value inside your span is "0", give this a try

**JQuery:**

```
if($(".link-badge").text() == "0"){
    $(".link-badge").addClass("link-badge-zero");
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nszmg82q/)